# Android - Losing the quality of PNG image OnDraw

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I have picture (particle picture, not moving, just single png), I preapared on photoshop, when 
On Android device, when you click the screen particle picture shows up, it is a bitmap on a sufraceview (drawed by OnDraw method), but it is terribly losing its quality

Any suggestions (See the test photoshop image and real screenshot from device) ?

Thanks

[image: Difference]

Comment: Looks like you saved your image as a 8-bit png (with a white matte). Try saving it as 24 bit instead.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. The image looks bad in android, but good from the browser of android mobile. My android is v2.3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the png with high quality(24)

Comment: de you select a size and quality?

  
  BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sFoto, options);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same issue, but I was getting a blurry png image too which I reference from an ImageView in my layout xml file.  It is a 24 bit image also, but it wasn't until I saved the image with a larger width and height that it actually looked good.  I went from a width of 88 to 250 and now the image looks great.